# IllegalStateException with Google App Engine Local Datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, runtime-error, illegalstateexception

So I'm trying to run a Google `App` Engine with the `Datastore` locally to test and debug. The local `App` Engine seems to work on its own, as does the `datastore` emulator.

But as soon as I set the environment variables for the `datastore` emulator, and restart the local App Engine, it crashes with the error,

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must use project ID as app ID if project ID is provided.
```

I've attached a more complete stack trace below

From the error message, I suspected I need to change my project id to the project name instead. So I tried replacing various instances of the project id with the project name where I could and unfortunately this did not work either.

Commands I'm running:

```
1. gcloud config set project PROJECT-ID
2. export ENDPOINTS_SERVICE_NAME=name.endpoints.PROJECT-ID.cloud.goog
3. gcloud beta emulators datastore start
4. $(gcloud beta emulators datastore env-init)
5. mvn appengine:run
```

I've put the stack trace on pastebin 
https://pastebin.com/atcnYwrq

Answer (score 12):

I happened to stumble into a way to fix this.

```
export DATASTORE_USE_PROJECT_ID_AS_APP_ID=true
```

Comment: Worked for me, but what does it do?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else stumbles into this error, I haven't fixed the original error but if you use the [Remote API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/remoteapi) instead, it seems to setup a local datastore when RemoteCheck is false.

If you are using Objectify then you will need to use [Remotely](https://github.com/objectify/objectify-remotely), setup the CustomFactory and register it and make sure you have something like the following in your web.xml

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.packagename.OfyHelper</listener-class>
</listener>
```